# Поддержка уровня java в android проекте

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio

В switch принимает текст, но AndroidStudia ругается, на то, что поддержки java_1.7 в андроид проекте нет! Она предлагает включить поддержку но при компиляции выбрасывает ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

switch должен обязательно принимать текст.

**Что можно сделать с этим!? Возможно можно как-то задать уровень java ?**

P.S. 
*В структуре проекта указный путь к java 1.8*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте в `build.gradle` секцию

```
android {
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
  }
}
```

`compileSdkVersion` должн быть не меньше `19`

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Setting-language-level

Comment: а чтобы включить лямбды, нужно в гредл добавить те же строки но с 1_8?

Comment: Нет, 1.8 байткод на Андроид не поддерживается. Совсем. Если хочется лябд, посмотрите RetroLambda или Kotlin.

Comment: я понял ! спасибо!

Comment: Хорошие новости. С выходом нового компилятора для Android N можно будет использовать некоторые фичи Java 8, включая лямбды, для Android 2.3 и выше. http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2016/03/first-preview-of-android-n-developer.html

Comment: Вот тут описано как что включать и настраивать https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja ага, только после выхода этого компилятора в релиз придется ещё пол годика подождать пока он действительно станет похожим на релиз а не на альфу( Инстант ран вон до сих пор допилить не могут. Хотя с другой стороны инстант ран это совершенно новая фича, а Jack компилятор это просто форк эклипсовского компилятора проверенного годами, так что может и быстрее пригодным станет.